# c++ same strings not equal (char* actually)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a problem with passing an argument into my program, seems to not be equal to what I put in as argument, except they're identical. Turning them into a string makes them identical, but I would like to know why the initial duo isn't.

Here's my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc>1) {
    cout << "#" << argv[1] << "#" << endl;
    cout << "#" << "nomast" << "#" << endl;
    cout << (argv[1] == "nomast" ? "equal" : "not equal") << endl;

    string s1 = argv[1];
    string s2 = "nomast";
    cout << (s1 == s2 ? "equal after all" : "nope") << endl;
    system("pause");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I launch the compiled code with "call thingy.exe nomast" I get the output

```
#nomast#
#nomast#
not equal
equal after all
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My best idea is that I'm not handling the "char *argv[]" properly. Don't know how to handle it differently though.

Comment: `argv[1] == "nomast"` - that isn't how you compare char-array strings and/or char string literals, in either C or C++. [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), sir.

Comment: you want [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) to compare `char*`, `string` has a `==` operator that is able to compare the character arrays which is why that works. When you use `==` with `char*` this compares the pointer address not what it's pointing at

Comment: Different language (C), identical problem and solution. Duplicate here: [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my two tuples containing strings, created the same way, not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63724412/why-are-my-two-tuples-containing-strings-created-the-same-way-not-equal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are comparing pointers, in other word addresses, not their content.
Since you are using C++ I suggest you use `std::string` and compare such objects instead (as you did in your second comparison).

Otherwise, if you have to deal with C, just use the `strcmp` function from the C standard library.

Comment: Creating `std::string`s from `main`'s arguments is just overhead (creating copies) - if you receive C-Strings for whatever reason (in given case: main is just defined by standard that way...) and *don't need* a std::string afterwards anyway, just use `strcmp` even in C++!

Comment: @MaxLanghof Valid alternative, still you'd iterate twice over the C-string: once for determining length on construction, then for comparison. strcmp is superior in this case...

Comment: Ah, so == in C++ defaults to comparing only pointers' addresses, not checking pointed memory. Good to know, thanks! And I went with strcmp, because it's faster.

Comment: @nDARQ Be aware that this is the case for *any* pointer, no matter of which type!

Comment: @nDARQ Keep in mind that you can always use == and != for any pointers of same type. You can additionally use <, >, <=, >=, but ***only*** if both pointers point to the same array (or one past last element), otherwise it is undefined behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple, this line

```
 cout << (argv[1] == "nomast" ? "equal" : "not equal") << endl;
```

gives you not equal as you are comparing char* (pointers) and there are not equal to each other. This comparison is acutaly doing something like 0x00134 == 0x00345 both of these are under different memory adresses.

On the second case with std::strings there is special operator== which will compare you strings by characters which they contain.

To get the same result with first example you would need to do

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "nomast") == 0) //need to add #include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strcmp()` function to compare two C strings. For C++ strings you can use [`string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/).

Comment: C-strings (in contrast to `std::string`)!

Answer (score 0):

char *argv[] is a `char` array that makes a null terminated string, which indeed don't have overloaded `==` to test equality of the string. When you say `==` in statement `argv[1] == "nomast"` its actually comparing pointers.

Where in

```
string s1 = argv[1];
string s2 = "nomast";
```

s1 and s2 are string objects. Which have overloaded == to test equality.

To test equality of char string in first case use `if (strcmp(argv[1], "nomast") == 0)` function or you can write your own function to check equality. However today it is recommended to use standard library `std::string` for stings.

Comment: That's just pure overhead if you don't need the strings afterwards anyway. `std::string` creates copies of, so `strcmp` should be preferred...

Comment: if C++ is being used its recommended to use std::string. However I support your statement of overhead.

Comment: "*always*" is a bit too strong. Although in general C is preferred for, you could code in C++ as well on microcontrollers. Typically, though, you don't want dynamic memory allocation, so you wouldn't use `std::string` there either (as well as any STL containers  with exception of `std::array`)...

Comment: My point is: prefer `std::string` wherever you define your own interfaces, classes, etc. Convert a C-string to a `std::string` if you *want or need* to maintain a copy. But if your recive C-strings from unmodifiable API (such as with `main`) and just need read access (comparing, finding first occurence of specific character, ...), use C-API for efficiency.